# The Yearly Silly Trip - Chant vs Jingle?

Tags: word-request, lyrics, poetry

I was looking for a trick [mnemonic] for little children to remember the months of the year in order but I couldn't find any online. Then I made this below and called it The Yearly Silly Trip.

My question is: is what I did, a chant or jingle?

> **The Yearly Silly Trip**

---

> **January**‘s for Jane
>
> In **February**’s her fame
>
> In **March** she’ll march
>
> With **April**, from noon.
>
> And **May** rest in **June**,
>
> Then fly high in **July**
>
> Gusty **August**’s the awesome member
>
> Offered his gust till **September**
>
> That **October** will remember
>
> The fun till **November**
>
> Cause it’s over in **December**

---

> By Antiscam, Mr.Zero = F.S.

Comment: I think calling it a [**mnemonic ditty**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mnemonic+ditty%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22mnemonic+ditty%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5921j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would work for most people. It does have potentially negative overtones of "trivial, silly", but they're not necessarily out of place here anyway. And most alternatives would tend to unwantedly "elevate" the referent, since they would usually allude to "artistic" songs, poems, etc., which aren't really the kind of associations we're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a jingle. Jingles refer to adverts with catchy tunes. I think chants are for spiritual/religious singing that isn't really *singing* per se but more like repeating words in a rhyming manner. I also don't think that's what you want.

Could it be a **nursery rhyme**?